# Setting up an event label in google analytics to include and ID or the src url

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, html5-video

I'm trying to set up an event label for google analytics to include an list item ID or a src url when viewed in GA dashboard. I have an html5 video with a playlist and now I need to set GA with tracking events to show me played times, time update and so on. At the moment all videos within the playlist shows the same video label in GA and cannot identify which video is which so I was thinking if maybe there is a way in my code to include either an ID or the src url. the code i am using for the video player and playlist is below with the ga event jquery. I made a jsfiddle for this. Any help would be appreciated. https://jsfiddle.net/dn5pu2ru/

```
<section id="video-container">
    <video id="video-player" controls="controls" poster="" src=""></video>
    <div id="description" label="" type="text"> </div>
<ul id="playlist">
    <li id="videoweek1" movieurl="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" label="This is video number 1 " type="video/mp4" moviesposter="http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/screen.jpg">
<img src="http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/screen.jpg" class="video-thumbnail">
    </li>
    <li id="videoweek2" movieurl="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" label="This is video number 2 " type="video/mp4"> <img src="http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/screen.jpg" class="video-thumbnail"></li>
    <li id="videoweek3" movieurl="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" label="This is video number 3 " type="video/mp4"> <img src="http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/screen.jpg" class="video-thumbnail"></li>
    <li id="videoweek4" movieurl="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" label="This is video number 4 " type="video/mp4"> <img src="http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/screen.jpg" class="video-thumbnail"></li>
    <li id="videoweek5" movieurl="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" label="This is video number 5 " type="video/mp4"> <img src="http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/screen.jpg" class="video-thumbnail"></li>
 </ul>
 </section>

<script>
$(function() {
    $("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
        $("#video-player").attr({
            "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
            "poster": "",
            "autoplay": "autoplay"
        })
    })
     $("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
        $("#description").attr({
            "label": $(this).attr("label")
        }).text($(this).attr("label"))
    })
    $("#video-player").attr({
        "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl"),
        "poster": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("moviesposter")
    })
})


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false)
      var videoId = document.getElementById('video-player')
      //var videoTitle = videoId.getAttribute('data-description')
      var videoTitle = 'Video News'

      function init () {
        videoId.addEventListener('ended', videoEnd, false)
        videoId.addEventListener('timeupdate', videoTimeUpdate, false)
        videoId.addEventListener('play', videoPlay, false)
        videoId.addEventListener('pause', videoPause, false)
      }

      function setKeyFrames (duration) {
        var quarter = (duration / 4).toFixed(1)
        sessionStorage.setItem('one', quarter)
        sessionStorage.setItem('two', (quarter * 2).toFixed(1))
        sessionStorage.setItem('three', (quarter * 3).toFixed(1))
      }

      function videoTimeUpdate () {
          var curTime = videoId.currentTime.toFixed(1)
          switch (curTime) {
            case sessionStorage.getItem('one'):
              ga('send', 'event', 'video', '25% video played', videoTitle)
              sessionStorage.setItem('one', null)
            case sessionStorage.getItem('two'):
              ga('send', 'event', 'video', '50% video played', videoTitle)
              sessionStorage.setItem('two', null)
            case sessionStorage.getItem('three'):
              ga('send', 'event', 'video', '75% video played', videoTitle)
              sessionStorage.setItem('three', null)
          }
      }

      function videoEnd () {
        ga('send', 'event', 'video', '100% video played', videoTitle)
      }

      function videoPlay () {
        ga('send', 'event', 'video', 'video played', videoTitle)
        setKeyFrames(this.duration)
      }

      function videoPause () {
        ga('send', 'event', 'video', 'video paused', videoTitle)
      }
```